# Proplem with setup AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I try write on AndroidAnnotations. I made all according to instructions,but 
when i compile this simple code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;


@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

i have this error

```
Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation folder [D:\Java\Android\PNU2DietCode\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out])
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
       ...
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity_">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and .MainActivity_ is unresolved

Gradle

```
...

def AAVersion = '4.6.0'
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. I had gradle `3.5`, but he doesn't support it(maybe). I instal gradle `3.3` and he work